# Grub doesn't show option to boot Devuan

Tags: debian, grub, devuan

I have Devuan installed and dual-booting with Windows 11, last time I was using my computer (on Devuan) I uninstalled and reinstalled some ncurses packages and libraries and now when I turn on my computer the only option is "UEFI Firmware Settings"

I tried loading the linux kernel but there wasn't any file called "vmlinuz" or anything similar in either / or /boot and I was in the correct partition.

What happened and how can I fix it?